# Odoo can't transfer (stock move) from different locations

Tags: location, odoo-8, stock, picking

Hello I'm trying to make a delivery (outgoing stock move) from different locations (all Internal Locations), but this gives me the error:

> The source location must be the same for all the moves of the picking.

The locations are, WH/Stock/01 and WH/Stock/02. Both are Internal locations and Stock is a view location.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the basic concept of the odoo is that one picking have many product move-lines and the restriction is source and destination both are same if you not follow then got en error.

If you want to change the flow then you can through stock module and in stock module have one method "_prepare_pack_ops", customise it.

Thank you